# different result from git log and git rev-list

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to get commits that exist in branch A, but does not exist in branch B. I thought these two commands will give me the same result, but they don't.

```
git rev-list A ^B --no-merges | wc -l
git log A ^B --no-merges | wc -l
```

The first one gives me 370, while `log` returns 8000. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Did you even try looking at the output without piping it through `wc -l`?

Comment: Oh different formats..

Comment: try `git log --oneline A ^B`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output from `git rev-list` is (by default at least) just the commit hashes:

```
$ git rev-list HEAD^..HEAD
e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c
```

The output from `git log` is, by default, rather a lot more verbose:

```
$ git log HEAD^..HEAD
commit e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 21 12:45:35 2018 -0800

    Fourth batch for 2.17
```

The first is one line (for one commit), the second is five lines (for a commit whose log message is just one line long).  The minimum ratio is therefore five-to-1, and:

```
$ echo 10k 8000 370 / p | dc
21.6216216216
```

shows that your ratio is almost 22-to-1, suggesting that most of your log messages are about 18 lines long on average.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly git `git log` is the same like git rev-list, but with a special format.
in both `git log` and `git rev-list` you can specify the format.

I made an alias for me to have a nice oneline output of git log, yust try this:

`git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%ad %h %<(15,trunc)%C(dim white)%an %C(auto)%d %s"`

it should print the same number of lines like `git rev-list` but in a better human readable format, including date, Authors, short-commit-hast and commit-message